# What is this (internet?) window in Windows 10 and how can I close it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet-connection

I am using Windows 10. It has happened several times that following window showed up in the right-hand corner of the screen:
[image]

I am not sure, but it is possible that it opens while connecting to wifi, or while opening a Zoom call.

The annoying thing is that it stays on top of everything, and I cannot close it (without closing the current session).

--> How can I find out what it means and how to close it (without closing the current session)?

I understand it is difficult to answer this question like this, but I would like to know how to prevent this window from appearing during a videoconference.

**Update**

- Once, shortly after the described problem occurred, the computer restarted and showed a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error on a blue screen, but this might be unrelated to the issue.
- I mistakenly indicated the Windows version to be Windows 7, but it is actually Windows 10.

Comment: I would say, its an advertisement banner that is being blocked of internet and instead of showing an advertisement, it shows a no internet symbol instead

Comment: I disconnected the machine beside me. That icon is not precisely what the disconnect icon in the tray is. See if you can get the properties.

Comment: @LPChip I closed all browsers, and the window is still showing.

Comment: @John The problem is I cannot obtain properties. The window just showed up. I cannot click on it. I also do not find its process in the task manager.

Comment: Run your Windows 7 AntiVirus (Full Scan) to see if that picks it up.

Comment: @John Nothing found.

Comment: Windows 7 is long past over, but you can try a Windows 7 Repair Install. You need your Windows 7 DVD to do this.

Comment: You have a third-party application that is displaying that icon.  You will want to use something like AutoRuns to determine what unnecessary programs are automatically to determine the culprit.  Unless you provide more information we won't be able to help identify the culprit.

Comment: Yes, closing your browsers won't do it. This is likely malware. Run Malware Bytes and do a full scan.